# How to insert a new line and move a value to it

Tags: powerquery, m

There's probably an easy way to do this with PowerQuery, but I can't think of it. I want to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

...Basically just copying the first instance of each ACODE into an inserted line as a Keyword above its associated other keywords:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group on ACODE with option All Rows, then add a row to the nested tables, remove the original ACODE column and expand the column with nested tables.

```
let
    Source = Input,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ACODE"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table}}),
    #"Inserted Row" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"AllData", each Table.InsertRows(_,0,{[ACODE = null, Keyword = _[ACODE]{0}]})}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Row",{"ACODE"}),
    #"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "AllData", {"ACODE", "Keyword"}, {"ACODE", "Keyword"})
in
    #"Expanded AllData"
```

Comment: Marcel, Thanks for the assist...again. The line for #"Inserted Row" must be added in the Advanced Editor, right? Or is there a way to do it using the GUI?

Comment: Base code can be created using the GUI: in this case I selected column ACODE and chose Transform - Format - Trim. Then I adjusted the code in the formula bar to the code listed above. If you don't have a formula bar: go to the View tab and check Formula bar.

Comment: Thanks yet again!